# Связь между 4 таблицами Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Всем привет, есть 3 модели фильтра

```
//Filter

class Filter extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'id',
        'name',
        'visible',
        'visible_category',
    ];

//FilterAttribute

class FilterAttribute extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'id',
        'filter_id',
        'value',
    ];

}

// ProductAttribute

class ProductAttribute extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'id',
        'filter_attr_id',
        'product_id',
    ];
}
```

Мне нужно при получении товара выводить значения атрибутов фильтра для этого товара
В моделе Product сделал такую связь

```
public function ProductAttribute()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(ProductAttribute::class, 'filter_attributes', 'filter_attr_id');
    }
```

Вывожу так

```
$products = Product::where('autor_id', '=', $user_id)->with('ProductAttribute')->get();
```

Но получаю ошибку, подскажите как правильно организовать связь
Ошибка:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'filter_attributes.filter_attr_id' in 'on clause' (SQL: select `filter_attributes`.*, `product_attributes`.`product_id` as `laravel_through_key` from `filter_attributes` inner join `product_attributes` on `product_attributes`.`id` = `filter_attributes`.`filter_attr_id` where `product_attributes`.`product_id` in (?))
```

Comment: А что за ошибка? И логичней в продукте использовать подобную связь `return $this->hasMany(ProductAttribute::class)` судя по вашим моделям

Comment: Сделал связь другую return $this->hasManyThrough(FilterAttribute::class, ProductAttribute::class, 'product_id', 'filter_attr_id', 'filter_attr_id', 'id'); Получаю другую ошибку(приложил выше)

Comment: Если вот так сделать
return $this->hasManyThrough(FilterAttribute::class, ProductAttribute::class, 'filter_attr_id', 'id', 'id', 'filter_attr_id');
То в  FilterAttribute выборка по id=product_id, а нужно id=filter_attr_id

Comment: Насколько помню `->hasManyThrough(FilterAttribute::class, ProductAttribute::class, 'id', 'product_id', 'filter_attr_id', 'id')` как то так в вашем случае

Comment: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'filter_attributes.product_id' in 'on clause' (SQL: select `filter_attributes`.*, `product_attributes`.`id` as `laravel_through_key` from `filter_attributes` inner join `product_attributes` on `product_attributes`.`id` = `filter_attributes`.`product_id` where `product_attributes`.`id` in (?))

Comment: return $this->hasManyThrough(FilterAttribute::class, ProductAttribute::class, 'product_id', 'id', 'id', 'filter_attr_id'); вот так правильно, но сейчас появилась потребность получить еще название фильтров, это уже модель Filtr, получатется мне не подходит уже hasManyThrough?

Comment: Так вы сделайте в FilterAttribute зависимость к фильтру и получайте его через связь

Comment: Сделал вот такую зависимость `public function GetFilter()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Filter::class, 'filter_id', 'id');
    }`

Comment: А получать как?
В моем случае `$products = Product::where('autor_id', '=', $user_id)->with('ProductAttribute')->with('Characteristic')->get();`

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116977/discussion-between-walfter-and-razrab345).